# Enlarge image without blur

Tags: android, xml, image

I have got a very tiny image:

[image]

(image made on gimp, it would be invisible if I pasted it here)

It's 5x5px in size and it has some pixels with 100% transparency and others with 80%.

I'm trying to use it as a background for an `ImageView`. I want to scale it to higher dimensions. However, when I do that, the overall effect becomes blurry and not what I truly want.

**XML Layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="500dp"
        android:layout_height="500dp"
        android:background="@drawable/boxes"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Unwanted result**

[image]

**Question**

How do I make it look good? That is, with sharp corner squares.

Answer (score 0):

Investigate using an SVG for the background - these should appear sharp at all sizes

Answer (score 0):

At first, try to resize it MS paint. If this process fails, take a screenshot of that picture to get a more clear view and then resize it again.